# Bing Traffic API Not returning any data for Accidents/Delays?

Tags: bing, traffic

I am interested in using the Bing Traffic API to get information about traffic incidents along a specified location. I have the correct Bounding Box Co-Ordinates and they show up accurately along a location where I am interested in getting incident data for. However when I query the API with these co-ordinates, I do not get any data returned. The only incidents I do see are for road closures. I do not see any info for delays or accidents.

I am using the below HTTP URL for Query. There was a traffic congestion. I even checked on Bing Maps which showed red along the road. Am I doing anything wrong?

I even specified the type of traffic incidents to report. Still the output has "Resources Set" = 0.

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Traffic/Incidents/40.812728881835938,-74.035232543945313,40.847114562988281,-73.988388061523438/true?t=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9&s=1,2,3,4&key=MY_KEY&o=xml

Thanks,
Kush

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I figured out the Traffic API returns point based information for known traffic issues such as planned road closures, construction and some accidents (not all accidents are reported into traffic systems). Traffic flow information (color coded road info) is not returned by the REST services, that information is only available as a tile layer in the Bing Maps controls. When viewing traffic on the map, any of the icons that appear on top of the map is the data that comes from the Traffic API. In summary, actual data point info (lat,long,type of accident) etc is not available through Bing Maps API